# How can I change the label name of a field and it's data also?

Tags: templates

I'm attaching the file as it's easier to explain. I want to change the label of a field, and also the resulting data. Kind of like changing both the fields and it's display in Drupal.

Can I do this with a find and replace in PhpMy admin?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could clarify more - changing Household to have First/Last name is quite a twist and maybe something that could be done more directly using existing civicrm features like Relationships or Contact Reference fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Word Replacement to change eg Household Name via /civicrm/admin/options/wordreplacements?reset=1 but what you are needing to do may be better accomplished via another mechanism (see comment above)

Comment: Yes, that's EXACTLY what I wanted to do, thank you!